# dokerize node node js application

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have a node JS application which i run on EC2.

This app runs fine on EC2 machine and when i do

```
https://domain-name-of-ec2:3000
```

It loads the application.

Now i am trying to containerize this application and created a docker file,image and ran container.

It shows container ran success and docker ps shows container running. I used below command

```
docker run -d image-id -p 3001:3000
```

Now when i try to load page its done not work.I am using below url

```
https://domain-name-of-ec2:3001
```

Comment: Could you show what you docker file looks like?

Comment: Try it without "https", i mean omit "s" from https , http://domain-name-of-ec2:3001 , if it works provide SSL to your docker container

Comment: Tried with http but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you said it works with the port 3000, but with port 3001 its not working, it should be most probably a security group issue, and you will need to change your security group definition attached to the EC2 machine, and add a new entry with

**type** - **Custom TCP**,

**Port Range** - **3001**,and

**Source** - **Anywhere-IPv4**(or choose otherwise, if there is any restriction), and

Save rules.

[image]

Comment: SG and NACL allows all ports from given IP

Comment: Can you share the security group entries for better help?

Comment: SG group allows all TCP traffic from VDI CIDR.As its dev env even i tested with All traffic from 0.0.0.0/0 but no luck

Comment: Can you check with running the node application on 3001 **without docker**, to confirm whether some restriction is on the port or there is some issue with docker?